# Want to migrate a livelink application to MOSS 2010 application.How to achieve that

Tags: 2010, migration

Apart from the docAve tool that is readily available, how to migrate features or security persmission or versions of any item or document from livelink to sharepoint 2010?

Comment: Can anybody please help me out on this. How can we migrate or relate any custom functionality of LiveLink in SharePoint? Will be really helpful if anybody can come up with any idea.